# Regex capturing groups of numbers in a list

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that I want captured into 4 different groups

```
5.00000 3.00000 0.00000 3.00000
```

Currently I'm using `(\s?\b([0-9].[0-9]+)\b\s?)` but it seems to only capture the first number.  I need it to capture all groups into an array so I can iterate through them.

I'm new to regex and I couldn't find this particular question anywhere, I may or may not need the word boundaries

Comment: Specify the language you're using. In some languages, you would need to use the `g` modifier. In other ones you need to do it programmatically. For example in php you would use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`. In java it's another story. TLDR: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using php and http://www.regexr.com/ to test

Comment: So first of all, I would recommend to use https://regex101.com since it supports PCRE which PHP uses. The site you linked does not support it although you could use it for simple use-cases. Next, I would remove capturing groups and the redundant optional whitespaces `\s?`. It should look like this `\b[0-9].[0-9]+\b`. In the [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eH8xF9/1) I used the `g` modifier but in real code you need to remove the `g` modifier and use `preg_math_all()` instead of `preg_match()`. See [**PHP demo**](https://eval.in/237097).